# Why does the filter property effect the width of the ::after element?

Tags: html, css

I am just working a game and was creating a custom button tooltip and observed something very string.

Here is first snippet with out `filter`

```css
button{
  padding: 5px;
}
button:hover::after{
  content: "A quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog";
   position: absolute;
   left: 60px;
   background: gray;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Text</span></button>
```

Snippet with `filter`

```css
button{
  padding: 5px;
  filter: brightness(0.8)
}
button:hover::after{
  content: "A quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog";
   position: absolute;
   left: 60px;
   background: gray;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Text</span></button>
```

When I use `filter: brightness` on button the text of `::after` started wrapping. I can't think of any relation between `filter` and wrapping of `::after`. I know I can fix that using `white-space:nowrap`. But I want to know the reason why the text started wrapping when I used `filter()`

Comment: first duplicate to explain what is happening with filter and second duplicate to explain the behavior of position:absolute and the wrapping

Answer (score 0):

When you set `filter: brightness(0.8)` to the `button` it becomes the [positioning context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Positioning_contexts) for the `::after` pseudo-element instead of the body. It's similar to setting position other than `static` to the button.

In this example, I've removed the filter, but added `position: relative` to the button, and the result is the same:

```css
button{
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}
button:hover::after{
  content: "A quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog";
   position: absolute;
   left: 60px;
   background: gray;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Text</span></button>
```